# Закрыть уязвимость CVE-2007-2768

Tags: openssh

Проверяю свой сервер с помощью `securitymetrics.com`, но возникает проблема: метрика жалуется что у меня в версии `openssh 9.0p1` (самой последней на данный момент) есть уязвимость с кодом `CVE-2007-2768`. Игнорировать не выйдет т.к мне необходимо что-бы метрика прошла полностью успешна.
Я уже вычитал что это связано с `OPIE` для `PAM`, но конкретного решения  как устранить эту ошибку я не нашел, всюду пишут что это не смертельная ошибка и спец патчей под неё не выходило.
Вот что пишет метрика:

> Apply the latest vendor patches to the OpenSSH 9.0 service running on
> port 22.
> Data Received
> cpe:2.3:a:openbsd:openssh:9.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
> CVEs
> CVEScoreVector
> CVE-2007-27684.3AV:N/AC:M/Au:N/C:P/I:N/A:N

Comment: Обновите ПО, связанное с этой ошибкой, чтобы не было уязвимости. А в чем вопрос? :)

Comment: @gil9red а что, после openssh 9.0p1 уже вышла какая-то ещё более новая версия?

Comment: @andreymal, было бы очень хорошо, если бы эта информация была написана в вопросе. А то тут не только знатоки версий openssh ходят...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137516/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-andreymal).

Comment: Я поставил самую последнюю версию, дело не в этом, а в том что необходимо отключить в PAM, или возможно сам PAM что-бы эта ошибка пропала, но вот что и где - не понимаю.

Comment: А вам этот самый OPIE вообще нужен? Его кто-нибудь специально настраивал или у вас настройки по умолчанию или вы не в курсе? Какая конкретно версия ОС у вас на сервере?

Comment: стоит ubuntu 20.04, нет - никто не настраивал OPIE или PAM он собрался вместе с openssh 9.0, и настройки стоят по умолчанию, сейчас пробую пересобрать без pam модуля openssh 9.0 может поможет и если выйдет - отпишу, только сам допер что можно без него собрать

Comment: PAM-модуль отключать лучше не надо, на него завязана вся авторизация в современных линуксах

Comment: Понял,  сам PAM у меня стоит в системе, но при повторной сборки я его исключил, и ничего не слетело, сейчас повторно запустил метрику, и жду отчет

Comment: не помогло, исключение PAM из сборки openssh